# Redirect To Specific Page

Tags: windows, web

What is the problem when we cannot connect to specific domain .

For example  , we cannot visit hotmail.com.

Comment: I don't think your question belongs here. Please go through the FAQs [http://stackoverflow.com/faq]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information it's hard to tell but here are a few possibilities:

- An issue on your connection. If you *can* visit other remote sites, that's obviously not the problem.
- An issue on one of your ISP connections. Can you visit other sites in the same area/country as the site that you cannot visit?
- An explicit filter that restricts access to that site. For example, some ISPs block YouTube, corporations may block their competitors' networks, governments block sites that allow their political opponents to speak up, educational institutions (attempt to) block porn sites and aware parents block as much as they can on the computers of their children.
- A DNS server issue that does not allow that site to be resolved. If you know its IP address you can try that directly.
- Connectivity problems from that remote site or its ISP. DDoS attack on the network of an ISP or hosting provider can easily disable a large number of sites at the same time.
- The problem site could simply experience server problems or be overloaded. Major sites like Hotmail are far more unlikely to be affected like this, although a DDoS attack can bring a site on its knees.
- Someone in your corner of the Internet (or you, for that matter) has been *bad* (sic), and the remote site has temporarily blocked your IP address range to protect themselves.

There are other alternatives, of course, but debugging network issues is impossible with a problem description of "it don't works anymore"...